# Why does my material look like this

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

Please forgive me if this is a newbie question, I am a newbie to Blender and 3D software in general. Why does my material look like this?

[image: Streaky materials]

[image: Better result based on moonboots feedback]

Comment: Hello, it looks like bad unwrapping, you need to correctly unwrap this part, take a look at your UV Editor

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will do a little research in that area.

Comment: Hi Dana, if you provide your blend file, we can give you a step by step explanation…

Comment: Thank you for the offer Chris. Moonboots reply got me off in the correct direction.